# Symfony2 validation changes invalid integer to 0

Tags: symfony

I added validation to a form and found that in some cases it is losing the invalid data I am feeding it and saving 0s instead. The output at the bottom shows that if I post the latitude as '`zzzzzz`', which is clearly not a number nor between -90 and 90, the form is declared as valid and saved with the value `0`.

How can that happen given that I have declared the input must be a number?

ProxyType.php buildForm():

```
$builder
        ->add('siteName', null, array('label' => 'Site name'))
        ....
        ->add('latitude', 'number', array('label' => 'Latitude'))
        ->add('longitude', 'number', array('label' => 'Longitude'))
        ....
    ;
```

ProxyController.php createAction:

```
    ....
    $postData = $request->request->get('niwa_pictbundle_proxytype');
    $this->get('logger')->info('Posted latitude = '.$postData['latitude']);

    $form    = $this->createForm(new ProxyType(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->get('logger')->info('Form declared valid : latlong ('.$entity->getLatitude().','.$entity->getLongitude().')');
        ....
```

validation.yml:

```
Acme\PictBundle\Entity\Proxy:
properties: 
    longitude:
        - Min: { limit: -180 }
        - Max: { limit: 180 }
    latitude:
        - Max: { limit: 90 }
        - Min: { limit: -90 }
```

Output:

```
[2012-09-28 02:05:30] app.INFO: Posted latitude = zzzzzz [] []
[2012-09-28 02:05:30] app.INFO: Form declared valid : latlong (0,0) [] []
```

Comment: I could n't get your question completely. I think you need to validate a field with only numbers is it right?

Comment: Yes. I've marked the field as numbers in the buildForm method and set max/min in validators.yml. But when I try to check it is working by submitting a string it saves the field as a 0 instead of saying something like "this value is invalid".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is you're not using a number validation, but rather bounding the form field to be a number, thus when you bind the request to the form it transforms the string into a number (which for any string which starts without a number will be 0). A form field being a number means it expects to come as a number, or rather, there should be some validation in the front-end of such thing or the front-end should not allow a non-number to be set.

I think what you seem to want is a form field of type text with a number validation.

For actual validation use the constraint type (additional to your min and max values).

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html

Comment: I put in some debug statements to look at what was being submitted it. It definitely gets to the request as a string of 'zzzzzz'. Then the form is bound to that request and passes validation. I haven't manually set up any filters anywhere in the project nor any casting. This is my first ever Symfony2 project and form so there isn't any part of the code (that I have written, possibly standard S2) that is doing a conversion.

Comment: I fixed my answer, sorry for the confusion, I hope that clears it.

Comment: With form type of text and validation type of numeric, min and max I get three warning messages. Submitting a string gets me "This value should be of type numeric" once and "This value should be a valid number" twice. If I remove the Max constraint it removes one of the repeated messages. It seems obvious that anyone validating a maximum would have o validate it was a numeric, but no-one would want two messages about it. So this behaviour must have been handled by many people before me.

Comment: So, the answer to your question was because the form field type was transforming your string. Max and min do validation by type too as it seems, you can either not do type validation or change the invalid messages of the constraints: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Max.html

Comment: Yes, changing the form field to 'text' instead of 'number' or null stopped the value from being converted to a number. And I don't need to define the type in validation because max and min do that for me. I'm still left with two invalidMessages being displayed because 'zzz' triggers a message from min and max. If I update to Symfony2.1 there is Range validator that should fix that.

Comment: You can write your own constraints if you want, or you can change the messages to be different. I personally recommend you do some client-side validation for such an easy thing to catch as if a text field is numeric or not. But yes, updating is probably the best and not just for that reason.

Comment: The trouble isn't what the messages say, it's that they are both triggered. I could change one to be an empty string but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: Well... the best solution to your issue is to upgrade to 2.1 and use range. If you can't upgrade, go to the source code, copy the constraint and validation files for Range and register the constraint in your project so you can use it.

Comment: Basically, avoid using number fields... if a user enters "123,000" then a number field with a range of "1 - 999999" would pass this through and save it as "123" (it drops everything after the first non-digit). Use text fields with the Range validator and you should get more sensible results!

Answer (score -1):

Add the following constarins in your validation.yaml. Then only it validated the fields.
In your form type you mention only which type(number) of widget you need. Thats not enough.
so try to add this validation in your

Validation.yml

```
latitude
    - Type:
        type: integer
        message: latitude should be numeric
longitude
    - Type:
        type: integer
        message: longitude should be numeric
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, latitude and longitude are values that usually want to be float.